# How can I get a simple c# web service to return <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" ?> header?

Tags: c#, web-services, utf-8, asmx, utf-16

I've written a very simple web service that returns an XML document.

The header for that document is currently 
    `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>`

and I would like it to return `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" ?>`

How can I change the default output encoding in the .asmx or .cs file?

```
smo.asmx
<%@ WebService Language="C#" Class="smo" %>


smo.asmx
using <blah>

[WebService(Namespace="http://www.bl.uk/webservices/")]
public class smo : WebService
{
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "SQLServer")]
    public class CDatabaseBackup
{
    public string ServerName;
    public string DatabaseCount;
     }

//
// Generic SMO query processor
//
[WebMethod(Description = "WMIClassProperty: ", EnableSession = false, CacheDuration=60)]

public CDatabaseBackup smoDatabaseBackupStatus(string SQLServerName)
{
    CDatabaseBackup result = new CDatabaseBackup();
    Server svr;
              <blah>
              return result;
      }
```

Ultimately this web service will be used within a SQL Server function and converted into an `xml` data type.  According to the documentation this needs to be `UTF-16`.

```
alter
procedure monitor_sqlbackupaudit 
as
begin

declare @l_xml_result   nvarchar(max)
set @l_xml_result   = ( select dbo.uspSMODatabaseBackup('sqlprod1vs') )
--set   @l_xml_result   = replace(@l_xml_result,'UTF-8','UTF-16');

declare @l_xml      xml
set @l_xml      = @l_xml_result

end
go
```

---

```
exec monitor_sqlbackupaudit

Msg 9402, Level 16, State 1, Procedure monitor_sqlbackupaudit, Line 15
XML parsing: line 1, character 38, unable to switch the encoding
```

Comment: If I cheat and uncomment the second "set" statement to replace UTF-8 to UTF-16 then the stored procedure works...  I'd rather not cheat, and I'm rather interested in getting this done right.  (Well, more right that the hack and paste I usually use:)

Comment: I can't quite see what you're doing. How are you creating the XML? You have to return the XML in the encoding which is expected.

Comment: The XML is created by returning the class, in this case CDatabaseBackup from the method I call.  It is automatically serialised into an XML document.  It appears that the C# framework will automatically create the <?xml > stuff but in my environment it uses UTF-8.

Comment: I think this is the same question...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760788/how-to-serialize-object-into-utf-8

Answer (score 1):

You can configure your web service to process UTF-16 instead of UTF-8 in the globalization section of Web.config. The requestEncoding and responseEncoding attributes of the globalization tag should be set to UTF-16.

```
<globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8"/>
```

must be converted to

```
<globalization requestEncoding="utf-16" responseEncoding="utf-16"/>
```

This change will allow the web service to output UTF-16, but it will also require the client to make its request in UTF-16.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into this.  I'll have to un-hack my hack to see if this works!!