# How can I get .net webservice to output UTF-16

Tags: .net, web-services, utf-16

I've got a .net 3.5 asmx webservice that we'd like to expand to support multi languages and we need the xml to be outputted as UTF-16, however the service will only output UTF-8

Is there any way that asmx webservices can be configured to output as UTF-16?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get a simple c# web service to return <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" ?> header?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146762/how-can-i-get-a-simple-c-sharp-web-service-to-return-xml-version-1-0-encodin)

Comment: I've looked at this and tried adding this to the config and it didn't change the encoding - it stayed as UTF-8

Comment: Have you tried changing .NET Globalization settings like described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19369044/5013033)