# Inserting XML file with encoding SHIFT-JIS error

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, t-sql, character-encoding

I have an XML file with SHIFT-JIS encoding as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="SHIFT-JIS" standalone="yes"?>
<海外管理ファイル><PO番号>GV05097</PO番号><データベース><PO><Tbl_PO_H PO番号="GV05097"><DATA><PO番号 TYPE="200" LENGTH="13">GV05097</PO番号></DATA></Tbl_PO_H></PO></データベース></海外管理ファイル>
```

And I use SQL store procedure to insert it into SQL table:

```
alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_TBL_PO_H_LoadXMLPO]
@xml  XML
AS  
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        INSERT INTO [ENVIETNAMPO].[dbo].[TBL_PO_H]
              SELECT
                  TBL_PO_H.value('(PO番号/text())[1]','varchar(13)') AS PO番号, --TAG
                  TBL_PO_H.value('(PO発行日/text())[1]','varchar(10)') AS PO発行日                  
              FROM
                 @xml.nodes('/海外管理ファイル/データベース/PO/Tbl_PO_H/DATA')AS TEMPTABLE(TBL_PO_H)      
    END
```

C# code for Load XML button:

```
string pathUser = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
            string pathDesktop = Path.Combine(pathUser, "Desktop");
            var xmlfilename = string.Empty;
            var xmlfilePath = string.Empty;
            //var dt = new DataTable();           
            var sqlConn = new SqlConnection(strConStr);
            try
            {
                    openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @pathDesktop;
                    openFileDialog1.Title = "Browse XML PO File";
                    openFileDialog1.Filter = "XML files (*.xml)|*.xml|All files (*.*)|*.*";
                    openFileDialog1.CheckFileExists = true;
                    openFileDialog1.CheckPathExists = true;
                    openFileDialog1.ShowHelp = true;
                    openFileDialog1.FileName = "*.xml";
                if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    xmlfilename =openFileDialog1.SafeFileName;
                    xmlfilePath = pathDesktop +"\\"+ xmlfilename;
                    string xml = File.ReadAllText(xmlfilePath, Encoding.GetEncoding("SHIFT-JIS"));
                    sqlConn.Open();

                    var cmd = new SqlCommand("proc_TBL_PO_H_LoadXMLPO", sqlConn);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@xml", xml);
                    SqlCommand arithabortCommand = new SqlCommand("SET ARITHABORT ON", sqlConn);
                    arithabortCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();  
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
                    sqlConn.Close();
                }

                    MessageBox.Show("PO XML File has been imported successfully.", "Information",
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                    MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
```

But when loading, an error occur as the following, I tried to read XML file with correct encoding  as the XML file. Please help me. Thank you!

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException 0x80131904: parsing XML Line 1, character 59. Cannot swicth I- code ....
```

Comment: I think Shift-JIS encoding setting uses underscore instead of dash (unlike UTF-8): `string xml = File.ReadAllText(xmlfilePath, Encoding.GetEncoding("shift_jis"));`. Can you provide what result returned by `xml` string to make sure?

Comment: Tried "shift_jis" and string xml = File.ReadAllText(xmlfilePath, Encoding.GetEncoding(932)); but it still get the same error

Comment: Well, your issue is related to `XML` data type used as parameter in stored procedure. Try getting rid of `AddWithValue` and use explicit data type: `cmd.Parameters.Add("@xml", SqlDbType.Xml).Value = xml;`. This issue may be similar to consider with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760788/how-to-solve-unable-to-switch-the-encoding-error-when-inserting-xml-into-sql-s.

Comment: I tried but it was unsuccessful. I think I must try to eliminate the XML header by C# code. It will be solved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get this correctly you are passing the XML *as is* from C# into a SQL-Server stored procedure. You do not state the actual RDBMS, but I assume this is SQL-Server (due to the error message about the "switch" of an encoding). Hope this is correct, if not, this might help with other databases too...

### Some things to know:

- Within C# XML is either the string you see, or an hierarchically organized document like `XmlDocument`.
- In any case, the XML is transposed into its string representation when you pass it over to the database (serialisation)
- All strings in C# are unicode. You can define a special encoding and shift an encoded string into a byte array, but the string type itself is unicode in any case.
- SQL Server will take the string and parse it into the native XML data type, which is a hierarchy table internally.
- All parts of the XML (tag names, content, ...) are stored in SQL-Servers `NVARCHAR`, which is kind of unicode (`UCS-2` actually).
- SQL Server will - in any case - not allow you to store this declaration together with the XML. It will be omitted in any case...

### So what is going on here:

You hand over a string, which is unicode actually, but the string tells the engine: *No, I'm `SHIFT-JIS`!*. This string is a liar :-D

This declaration is only needed if you store this XML in any byte container (like a file) and you want to tell a reader how to decode the content.

But between C# and the database there's no need to mess around: The string is plain unicode and will be taken into (almost) plain unicode.

### Easy solution:

Pass the XML without the `<?xml blah?>` declaration.

### UPDATE

About your question "how to strip of the declaration"?

At the moment when you've got the XML

> `string xml = File.ReadAllText(xmlfilePath, Encoding.GetEncoding("SHIFT-JIS"));`

You do not have an XML (native type), but you've got a (unicode) string which looks like an XML.

You can use any string method here:

- Use `.IndexOf()` to find `?>` (end of declaration) and use `.Substring()` to cut away the declaration entirely
- Use `.Replace()` to change your encoding to `encoding="utf-16"`
- Use RegEx, whatever you like...

On the other side you might pass the string to the stored procedure as `NVARCHAR(MAX)` (the SP's parameter) and do the *cut-off* there before SQL-Server tries to take this as XML. But I'd suggest to solve this on C# side.

Comment: In fact, removing `encoding="SHIFT-JIS"` seems to solve the XML conversion error (tested with MSSQL 2008)

Comment: I am having an issue that we receive xml files from other branches so I do not want to mannually remove <?xml blah?>.      Any way to skip this header by C# code?

Comment: I solved this issue now but i am facing with another problem is convert XML datatype <下代 TYPE="6" LENGTH="8">0.009</下代>  to money type in SQL . I used   TBL_PO_M.value('(下代)[1]','money') AS 下代  but cannot. Thanks

Comment: @user3035133 Please avoid follow up questions. Next time please start a new question. This is very easy: In `T-SQL` you must place an `N` before all your literals. Try this: `SELECT '(下代)[1]' AS without_N, N'(下代)[1]' AS with_N`