# Saving XML contents with ISO-8859-1 encoding using Entity Framework into SQL Server 2008's XML column gives encoding error

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, entity-framework

I am trying to save XML content with `encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes"` into a SQL Server 2008 XML column. I am doing this using Entity Framework.

However doing this throws the following error

> XML parsing: line 1, character 60, unable to switch the encoding

However when I try to save XML content with encoding **UTF-16**, it is saved without any error.

Does anyone have any inputs regarding this?

Answer (score 2):

The encoding width must match the datatype width

So *don't* send:

- UTF-8 and nvarchar/xml
- UTF-16 and varchar

Also see [Trying to store XML content into SQL Server 2005 fails (encoding problem)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384974/trying-to-store-xml-content-into-sql-server-2005-fails-encoding-problem/385756#385756) whcih links to http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlxml/thread/d40ef582-4ffe-4f4b-b6b8-03c6c0ba1a32/

Comment: The datatype of the column in SQL Server 2008 is xml and that of property of corresponding class generated by Entity Framework is string. Also I am sending data with encoding ISO-8859-1.

Comment: @surajnaik: xml is effectively nvarchar in this case. You **have** to change encoding.